# How do I build an ASP.NET Core 2 RC2 project in Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS)?

Tags: azure-pipelines, asp.net-core-2.0, .net-core-2.0

I have a ASP.NET Core 2 RC2 project that I want to setup CI for in Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS).  How do I do this?

Specifically, my problem is that the hosted build agents seem to only have .net core 1.1 installed.  They do not have a .NET Core 2 installed.  (I double-checked by running `dotnet --version` on them).

I know there are workarounds, such as setting-up my own build agent or adding steps to my build process to download and install the v2 SDK on a hosted built agent at the start of each build, but both of these would take some time.  Investing that time is probably not worth it for me, given that .NET Core 2 is still scheduled for release in Q3 (i.e. before the end of September).

I worked with the betas of .NET Core 1 and I (vaguely) remember that we were able to add a demand to the build that allowed us to request a hosted build agent that had a beta version of .net Core.  Is there anything like this for .net Core 2?

Thanks!

Comment: There is .Net Core Tool install task available now, add it to your build definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is **.NET Core Tool Install (Preview)** task available now, so you can add this task to build/release definition to install .Net Core 2.0. For example:

1. .Net Core Tool Installer
2. .NET core Restore
3. .Net Core Build

Comment: Awesome.  Works a treat.  Thanks.  Ideally, I would have to install the tools - they'd just be available in a hosted agent, but I'm just happy I can do a CI build quickly now.

Comment: BTW I notice that you have to specify the full version number (i.e. '2.0.0') in the '.NET Core Tool Installer' step.  What happens if/when a new dotnet patch version is released?  It looks like I'll need to manually update the build definition to use the patch SDK version (e.g. 2.0.1).  If if try and do '2.0.*' at the moment I get an error ('Version should be a valid and explicit version: 2.0.*').  Is there a plan for dealing with this?

Comment: @Simon You can submit a user voice.

Comment: apparently you can't use this for 2.0.0 (release) yet? It wouldn't let me save it unless I specified a build number.